# Is there any way to pass a char variable (my_char )and use it inside a fuction like reg.summary$my_char in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to write this code:

```
my_fun<-function(summary,typee){
  if(typee=="adjr2"){
    best <- which.max(summary$typee)
    }
  else{
     best <- which.min(summary$typee)
  }
}
```

But there is have a problem when I call my_fun(reg.summary,"adjr2")
since it turns to summary$"adjr2" not summary$adjr2.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe use `summary["typee"]` instead of `summary$typee`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to use functions from the `dplyr` package, then your code will work if edited to the following:

```
my_fun<-function(summary,typee){
  require(dplyr)
  if(typee=="adjr2"){
    best <- summary %>%
      summarize(across(typee, which.max))
  }
  else{
    best <- summary %>% 
      summarize(across(typee, which.min))
  }
  best
}
```

The `summarize()` function lets you use a do an operation that will return a single value, and the `across()` function allows you to select the desired column from within `summarize()`.

Here is an example using the built in data set `iris`.

```
my_fun(iris, "Sepal.Width")
  Sepal.Width
1          61
```

The code now returns the row number with the smallest value of `Sepal.Width`.